# Can we define a function inside def __init__ () in python

Tags: python

I  wish to use a function for initialisation of an instance variable, and hence have placed a function definition inside `def __init__(self)`. Is it a valid practice in python?

Comment: `__init__` is used to initialize instance attributes, why would you write another function inside it?

Comment: You have access to instance-level functions to define instance attributes, no need to define a function inside `__init__`

Comment: If you feel the need for a separate function, then yes, you can define it inside your `__init__` method.

Comment: I have an instance variable  which is dependent on other instance variables of the class. To initialise it I need a function

Comment: @ManpritSingh That doesn't make much sense to me.  Perhaps it would help if you posted the code you think you need?

Comment: `__init__` _is_ the "function for initialisation of an instance variable", you shouldn't need another function, just use the init function to do the work?